# Subscribe to ComboBox selection changed event with UI Automation

Tags: c#, .net, automation, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am new in UI-automatation.
There is an AutomationElement of type ComboBox.
I am looking for a way to subscribe to an event that is raised when the ComboBox changes its `Name` property.

This is what I'm trying to do but it doesn't work:

```
Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(
    elementComboBox,
    TreeScope.Element,
    new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnUIAutomationPropChanged),
    NameProperty
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you already know how to get to the ComboBox element, so let's just setup an [AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.addautomationpropertychangedeventhandler) to detect [ExpandCollapsePattern.ExpandCollapseStateProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.expandcollapsepattern.expandcollapsestateproperty) change events.

The ComboBox controls are composited objects composed of:

- The external container,
- The internal Edit Control, used to enter a selection/search a value, available when the ComboBox is of type DropDown
- The internal ListControl, used to present the list of items contained in the ComboBox, shown as a the ComboBox drop down element.

The item selection belongs to the ListControl, it's this control we need to get the value from.
The [List Automation Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-support-for-the-list-control-type) supports the [SelectionPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.selectionpattern).
The [SelectionPatter.GetSelection()](http://SelectionPattern.SelectionPatternInformation.GetSelection) method return a collection of `ListItem` elements: the **`Name`** property of the Item returns the current selection value.

With the AutomationElement identifying the ComboBox of interest, when can setup an event handler for its `ExpandCollapseState` property changes like this:

```
bool success = SetExpandCollapseEventHandler(elementComboBox);
// [...]
// Remove the handler when you're done with it
RemoveExpandCollapseEventHandler(elementComboBox);
```

Here, `string selectedValue` contains the value selected when the ComboBox is closed:
<sub>Of course, you could read the value both when the ExpandCollapseState is `Expanded` and `Collpsed`, to compare the current value and the selected one</sub>

```
private AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler ExpandCollapsedHandler = null;

public bool SetExpandCollapseEventHandler(AutomationElement element)
{
    if ((bool)element.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailableProperty)) {
        Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(element, TreeScope.Element,
            ExpandCollapsedHandler = new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnExpandCollapeChanged),
            ExpandCollapsePattern.ExpandCollapseStateProperty);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void OnExpandCollapeChanged(object elm, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = elm as AutomationElement;
    if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern, out object value)) {
        var state = (value as ExpandCollapsePattern).Current.ExpandCollapseState;
        if (state == ExpandCollapseState.Collapsed) {
            var listElement = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, 
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.List));
            if (listElement != null) {
                var selectedItem = (listElement.GetCurrentPattern(
                     SelectionPattern.Pattern) as SelectionPattern).Current.GetSelection().FirstOrDefault();
                string selectedValue = selectedItem?.Current.Name;
            }
        }
    }
}

void RemoveExpandCollapseEventHandler(AutomationElement element)
{
    Automation.RemoveAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(element, ExpandCollapsedHandler);
    ExpandCollapsedHandler = null;
}
```

---

► Subscribe to [SelectionItemPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.selectionitempattern)'s [ElementSelectedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.selectionitempattern.elementselectedevent):

If you need to know when any elements of the ComboBox List is changed/selected when no actual User selection is made using the GUI, you can subscribe to the events raised by the child elements of the `List` element.
You need just one handler, attached to a wider scope: `TreeScope.Children`.

**WARNING**: Since these events need to be handled asynchnonously, the events are raised in Threadpool threads.

This has consequences:

- you cannot access controls in the UI thread directly (you need to `BeginInvoke()`)
- You **MUST** remove the `AutomationEventHandler` if/when the ComboBox Control is disposed (e.g., when the parent Window is closed), otherwise your app will become unstable and probably stuck eternally waiting for an event to return a value from a Element that, at a certain point, doesn't answer anymore.

You may want to use a [WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowclosedevent) handler to receive notifications when the parent Window is closed, then call the `Automation.RemoveAutomationEventHandler` (as shown here), but probably (to evaluate based on the context of the operations) also the [Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.removealleventhandlers) method.

Called as:

```
bool success = SetListItemChangedEventHandler(elementComboBox);
// [...]
// Remove the handler when you're done with it
RemoveListItemChangedHandler();
```

---

```
private AutomationElement listElement = null;
private AutomationEventHandler ListItemChangedHandler = null;

public bool SetListItemChangedEventHandler(AutomationElement combobox)
{
    listElement = combobox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.List));

    if ((bool)listElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.IsSelectionPatternAvailableProperty)) {
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(SelectionItemPattern.ElementSelectedEvent, 
            listElement, TreeScope.Children, 
            ListItemChangedHandler = new AutomationEventHandler(OnListItemChanged));

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
        
private void OnListItemChanged(object elm, AutomationEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = (elm as AutomationElement)?.Current.Name;
}

private void RemoveListItemChangedHandler()
{
    Automation.RemoveAutomationEventHandler(
        SelectionItemPattern.ElementSelectedEvent, listElement, ListItemChangedHandler);
    ListItemChangedHandler = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works great when combobox collapse/expand. But the event doesn’t raise when the combobox change from outside. In my case combobox's items change from outside when User select some elements in the other control (actually in 3D space, but it sems not to be matter). Every time when the selection in 3D space is changed, item list and selected element of combobox changes too. I need to subscribe to any event that could notify about the combo box changed.

Comment: Well, you didn't describe any of this in your question. Edit the question and add all the specifics required to understand your scenario. No idea what a *3D space* means. Anyway, you probably just want to subscribe to the events of the ListControl instead of the ComboBox itself (as mentioned, the ComboBox is a composited control).

Comment: I've added a section related to the List Element's ListItems selection events.

Comment: Jimi! Thank you for such  a detailed answer. That works to me. I will add additional information in the question as soon as it possible